# doc is not working on my Visual Studio Code on Windows 8 laptop installation

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code

I am using Visual Studio Code on Windows 8 laptop.
When I type in doc tab the basic code is not being generated.
Did I miss something with the installing of Visual Studio code?

Comment: what is doc tab and what do you expect it to do?

Comment: Are you having problems only with the HTML boilerplate emmet abbreviation or with emmet in general? Anyway, you can refer to the [VSCode documentation for Emmet](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/emmet)

Comment: if @secan's suggestion doesn't work try using ```! tab```

Answer (score 0):

I selected html:5 and the skeleton code was generated.